# Semidirect product of two groups defined in terms of a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product

I am going through [From optimal measurement to efficient quantum algorithms for the hidden subgroup problem over semidirect product groups](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0504083v2.pdf) by Bacon et al.

I am having trouble to understand the definition of semidirect product in section 2.2. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

**My questions:**

1. Shouldn't the relation be $(a, b) (a', b') = (a + a', b+b')$ instead of being $(a, b) (a', b') = (a + \varphi(b)(a'), b+b')$?
2. What is the significance of $\varphi(b)(a')$ in this context?
3. I also try to verify the group inversion i.e. whether $(a, b) + (\varphi(-b)(-a), -b) = 0$.

$$(a, b) + (\varphi(-b)(-a), -b)$$
$$\implies (a + \varphi(-b)(-a), b -b)$$

I do not know how to proceed further from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** When $\varphi$ is the identity, the semi-direct product coincides with the direct product.

**2.** It generalizes the notion of direct product.

**3.**

\begin{eqnarray*}
(a,b)+(\varphi(-b)(-a),-b)&=&(a+\varphi(b)\varphi(-b)(-a),0)\\
&=&(a+\varphi(b-b)(-a),0)\\
&=&(a+\varphi(0)(-a),0)\\
&=&(a-a,0)\\
&=&(0,0)
\end{eqnarray*}